# Laravel 8: How can I convert base64 PDF to PDF file?

Tags: laravel, base64, laravel-8

I am trying to save a pdf and other documents file like Docx and video in the database using a base64.

what I want to do is to revert the changes from base64 to the exact file. is it possible to do that? thank you and stay safe.

I know it is a duplicate question, but I cannot find any answer in laravel.

Comment: Have you tried base64_decode() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decode and then pass to `Storage` put method

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('file.pdf',base64_decode($base64encodedstring));
```

don't forget to import Storage facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Comment: is it possible to use this method?
    $file->storeAs($destinationPath, $completeFileName);

Comment: Solved! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = 'upload/profile_pic/' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '_' . $input['document']['filename'];
file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($input['document']['base64']));
$input['document'] = $filename;
```

Decode file and save the file in the public path, **create upload folder in the public folder and save any file.**

Comment: Thank you. this helps me too  :)